# How can I reference CSS background images in production in Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I switched an app over from 3.2.12 to 4.0.0.rc1. When I viewed it in production afterwards, the background image had disappeared. The rest of my image assets were fetched with no problem.

In my logs, I saw that all the successfully rendered images had a digest tacked to the end of them, like so:

```
2013-05-12T19:57:05.856277+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/asset/explore-9ec2a1cfd4784133755637f6ef6d5673.png host=xxx.herokuapp.com fwd="69.140.148.75" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=4064
```

And my unsuccessful background image had no digest on it, plus a 404 response code:

```
2013-05-12T19:57:05.736354+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/background.png host=xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="69.140.148.75" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=728
```

In the production.rb file, there's a config line that enables this for caching purposes:

```
# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

This is the CSS for the background:

```
body {
  background-image: url('background.png');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I concluded that my CSS file was trying to fetch an image url that didn't exist, because it was referencing the plain asset ("background.png") without the hash at the end. This is only an issue for images in the CSS; all images referenced in my .erb files are fine. So how do I reference this asset in my CSS without hardcoding the digest in? Are there any workarounds?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `asset-url`. Rails will preprocess this and expand the proper url.

```
body {
  background-image: asset-url('background.png');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about this! Thank you. The background's displayed again.

Comment: I am having this exact problem, but when I change my line to use `asset-url` I get 'Invalid property value.' Any idea why?

Comment: `asset-url` takes a second argument `$asset-class`. Consider `asset-url('whatever.png', image)` for example. You can also write it using `image-url`: `image-url('whatever')`,

Comment: Wow I wish I knew about this a long time ago!