# css not loading image asset on rails 4

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image, assets

I am trying display one simple image from my assets images. I tries that in following manner:

```
#head {
background: #181015 url( ../images/header_bg.png) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 520px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 240px;
color: white;
font-family: "Open sans", Helvetica, Arial;
font-weight: 300;
}
```

In my `assets/images` folder I have other images as well. If I set other image then its working fine. But If I try to load above image then its not able to load that image. I put following things in my `environments/development.rb`

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

I also ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` but then also it is not able to load that image. That image is not having any issue. Because I tried with simple html page with same css which is working fine. Am I missing anything. Need some help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512080/how-can-i-reference-css-background-images-in-production-in-rails-4-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using *image-url* instead of *url*. You may need to change the path to just "header_bg.png" (instead of having the image directory included)

An example of something I had that worked:

[image]

Have you also tried restarting the server to see if that was the reason?

Rails sometimes handles assets differently than you would if you linked it with basic css. You may want to look at the documentation too:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

*Roughly around section 2.3.2*

Comment: Thank yo ufor quick replay `url( "header_bg.png") ` works for me